# how to perform command button operation which is placed in Excel sheet using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I want to automate the command button(want to perform click operation) which is placed on Excel sheet using selenium java code. How to do this? If any code is there please share?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate just browser interaction using selenium. You cannot interact with Microsoft Excel desktop version with selenium.

Comment: any other solution is there? other than selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for keyword framework to automate selenium

Look below articles they have shown the all necessary details regarding same:-

https://www.guru99.com/creating-keyword-hybrid-frameworks-with-selenium.html

http://www.lessons99.com/keyword-driven-framework.html

Go through all links of Keyword driven in below URL. You will get the code also

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/keyword-driven-framework/introduction/

Hope it will help you :)